# ImageMagick 'import' tool for MIPS Architecture

Tags: imagemagick, mips

Have a digital media device that I'd like to get the ImageMagick command-line tool 'import' working on. Trying to run binaries from other systems gives a "cannot execute binary" error since the architecture differs (I'm guessing).

How would I get this tool functioning on this MIPS architecture - there is no compiler or package manager on the device.

End goal is to use import to take screen-shots of what is on the attached display at any given time.

**uname -a**

```
Linux 4310 2.6.22.19-27-sigma #2 PREEMPT Mon May 16 01:03:35 PDT 2011 mips GNU/Linux
```

**more /proc/cpuinfo**

```
system type                : Sigma Designs TangoX
processor                : 0
cpu model                : MIPS 74K V4.9  FPU V0.0
Initial BogoMIPS        : 330.13
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers        : yes
tlb_entries                : 32
extra interrupt vector        : yes
hardware watchpoint        : yes
ASEs implemented        : mips16 dsp
shadow register sets        : 1
VCED exceptions                : not available
VCEI exceptions                : not available
System bus frequency        : 330750000 Hz
CPU frequency                : 661500000 Hz
DSP frequency                : 330750000 Hz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Mips has an entirely different instruction set.

Your best bet is to use a cross compiler and compile the program on a normal Linux or Windows development system. You can build gcc from scratch as a cross compiler for Mips, or you probably find downloadable pre-compiled compilers for Mips.

This would let you compile the sources on your development system. Of course you'll get the "cannot execute binary" if you try to run the binary there.

You can compare Mips and x86 compiles and look at the assembly language differences at http://ellcc.org/demo